# LWC -lightning-combobox not showing dropdown list

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox

I have a page with the following two lightning components inside a for:each -

```
<template for:each={selectedConfig.attributes} for:item="attrib">

     <template if:false={attrib.isPicklist}>
         <lightning-input type={attrib.webType} 
                          variant="label-hidden" 
                          name={attrib.externalName} 
                          onchange={handleValueUpdate}
                          placeholder={attrib.placeHolder}
                          pattern={attrib.textPattern}
                          value={attrib.value}>
         </lightning-input>
     </template>

     <template if:true={attrib.isPicklist}>
          <lightning-combobox name={attrib.externalName}
                             value={attrib.value} 
                             onchange={handleValueUpdate} 
                             options={attrib.picklistValues}>
         </lightning-combobox>
     </template>

</template>
```

The lightning-input component works great. The lightning-combobox does not. The combobox displays but does not show any default value, only the placeholder text. Also, when I click on the combobox it will not show me the list of values or allow me to select anything else.

[image]

It's like the combobox is readonly!

Client side javascript controller is as follows -

```
import getSelectedConfig from '@salesforce/apex/myUIController.getSelectedConfig';

export default class myUIProcess extends LightningElement {    
        @track error;
        @track selectedConfigOption;
        @track selectedConfig;

        @wire(getSelectedConfig, { processName: '$selectedConfigOption' })
        wiredSelectedConfigOption({ error, data }) {
            if (data) {  this.selectedConfig = data; this.error = undefined;}
            else if (error) { this.error = error; }
        }

        handleValueUpdate(event) {
            console.log('Do stuff.');
        }

    }
```

A few thoughts -

1. It works great for the input field so in my mind all the attrib data is available.
2. The attrib data is not read-only as I am able to input values (using the lightning-input component) and the values are retrieved and handled as expected.
3. I have used debugging on the back end Apex controller and the attrib.picklistValues are being picked up and returned as expected.
4. The attrib.getPicklistValues() method on the backend controller is @AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)

Anybody have an idea what the issue might be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally figured this one out! It had to do with not showing enough code in my initial example as I can guarantee someone would have spotted it. Here is the code I was working from -

```
     <div class="slds-truncate" title={attrib.value}>
         <template if:true={attrib.allowOverrides}>
             <template if:true={attrib.isPicklist}>
                 <lightning-combobox name={attrib.externalName}
                                     value={attrib.value} 
                                     onchange={handleValueUpdate} 
                                     options={attrib.picklistValues}>
                 </lightning-combobox>
             </template>
         </template>
     </div>
```

The issue was that I needed to remove the `class='slds-truncate'`. Once I did that the drop down list was allowed to show over HTML elements below it and everything worked as expected.

Easy fix. Hopefully this will help someone else!

Comment: Holy smokes, it worked. I've spent so much time digging around JS side, but it was simple CSS issue!

Comment: Life saver, 2 hours spent trying to solve this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the `value` as an attribute that can be modified. [Here's your code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/itJLSAcc/1/edit), modified:

```
<template>
    <lightning-combobox name="myLightningComboBox"
                    value={value}
                    onchange={handleValueUpdate} 
                    options={statusOptions}>
    </lightning-combobox>
</template>
```

---

```
import { track, LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {    
    @track statusOptions = [
        {value: 'new', label: 'New'},
        {value: 'in-progress', label: 'In Progress'},
        {value: 'finished', label: 'Finished'}
    ];
    @track value = 'new';

    handleValueUpdate(event) {
        console.log('Do something...');
    }

}
```

---

Comment: Not sure if its only me or the example by op works fine in playground.

Comment: @sfdcfox shucks....you caught me out. I was trying to show the issue I was having in as simple a way as possible but inadvertently reduced the code to the point you found something else! But, I think your answer has moved things forward. Let me update my question and try to clarify.

Comment: @Raul I just checked as well and it seems to work using the constant. Interesting. Regardless, I will update my question per my above comment to sfdcfox

Comment: @TomAnsley Happens to the best of us. It's probably something somewhere else. Let me know when you've updated, I'll take a look.

Comment: updates are in!